# How would you protect sudo from the user itself?

Tags: security, sudo

<sup>Dislaimer: Only an occasional *nix user. Just curious.</sup>

I was reading https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232924/is-sudo-almost-useless where the question raises the point

> Once an attacker has a shell as your sudoer user (or just compromised a local process enough), 
>   he/she can use one of the many privilege escalation tool ...

and [answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/232968/3785) [show](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/232930/3785) how an attacker that has compromised the user account can easily compromise `sudo` or any other privilege escalation mechanism, e.g. by injecting a fake `sudo` into `~/.bashrc`.

One answer states

> so long as you can avoid interacting with a fake *login screen*, you can mitigate this by having 
>   separate administrative and non-administrative user accounts

which got me thinking, that compromising root via a sudoer would be much harder if `sudo`, or really any privilege escalation mechanism, couldn't be faked with the same users rights that uses said privilege escalation mechanism.

*So, as a user, how would I make sure that the privilege escalation mechanism used cannot be tampered with by myself without prior privilege escalation?*

Note: [xkcd/1200](https://xkcd.com/1200/) applies, of course.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. However it is possible to not give a user `sudo` permissions, or to give permission to only run certain commands with `sudo`. See `man sudoers`

Comment: Also don't forget that `sudo` is not a mechanism to prevent "hackers" from taking over the computer once they've taken over a user account. It's a mechanism for multi-user systems to give some users additional privileges in a controlled manner, and to allow sysadmins to protect themselves against stupid mistakes by allowing them to work from non-root accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to protect an account against certain possible results of being compromised then take away the permission to do so. Set `.bashrc` and the other files (for `bash` and the other shells in `/etc/shells`) to immutable.

Or use Apparmor / SELinux to limit write access to those files.